# How to append to a specific line using shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have a file *(catalina.properties)* with a specific line of:
      `common.loader="${catalina.base}/lib","${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar"`

In another environment it looks like this:
      `common.loader=`

I would need a command which appends an extra part at the right side of the equal sign, and works in both of the 2 cases, so the result would be:

```
common.loader="${catalina.base}/lib","${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar","${catalina.base}/extra/part.jar"
```

or in the other case:

```
common.loader="${catalina.base}/extra/part.jar"
```

Comment: how it should distinguish those 2 cases?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to, if there is an additional comma at the second case (like in the first one) that's fine too. Though in that case the additional part should be the first, after the equal sign, and the comma would need to go after that. (Instead of being the last parameter, and adding a comma before that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**sed** solution:

exemplary test input file `testfile`:

```
common.loader="${catalina.base}/lib","${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar"
common.loader=
"ddd""sdsd"
```

---

```
sed 's~common\.loader=.*~&,"${catalina.base}/extra/part.jar"~; s/=,/=/' testfile
```

The output:

```
common.loader="${catalina.base}/lib","${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar","${catalina.base}/extra/part.jar"
common.loader="${catalina.base}/extra/part.jar"
"ddd""sdsd"
```

Comment: That's almost perfect, thank you! Can you please add how to replace the original content of the file, with the new one?
 If I lead the result to the file like ` >> testfile ` it will append it to it instead of replacing. (I want to avoid creating a temporary file to store the new value and then replacing the original file) Thank you!

Comment: @Mr.Fireman, welcome. To modify the file in-place add `-i` option in following format `sed -i <expression>`

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following awk and let us know if this helps you.
NON-ONE liner form of solution:

```
awk -v base="\${catalina.base}/lib" -v ja="\${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar" -v s1="\"" -v extra_part="\${catalina.base}/extra/part.jar" -v s2="," '
/common.loader=$/{
  sub(/.*/,"&"s1 base s1 s2  s1 ja s1 s2 s1 extra_part s1);
  print;
  next
}
/common.loader=.*jar\"/{
  sub(/.*/,"&" s2 s1 extra_part s1);
  print;
  next
}
1
'   Input_file
```

One line form of solution:

```
awk  -v base="\${catalina.base}/lib" -v ja="\${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar" -v s1="\"" -v extra_part="\${catalina.base}/extra/part.jar" -v s2="," '/common.loader=$/{sub(/.*/,"&"s1 base s1 s2 s1 ja s1 s2 s1 extra_part s1);print;next} /common.loader=.*jar\"/{sub(/.*/,"&" s2 s1 extra_part s1);print;next}1'  Input_file
```

Also as you need the Input_file itself to be edited, so you could add following code at the end of the above codes and could do the same

```
.... > tmp_file && mv tmp_file Input_file
```

**EDIT1:** If you want to add only extra part in either of the conditions then you could try following.

```
awk -v s1="\"" -v extra_part="\${catalina.base}/extra/part.jar" '
/common.loader=/{
  s2=$0 ~ /=$/?"":",";
  sub(/.*/,"&" s2 s1 extra_part s1);
  print;
  next
}
1'   Input_file
```

Comment: Thank you!

 Unfortunately when I try to run them, I get this error:
"awk: invalid -v optio"

Comment: try with -v s1, I mean give a space between them and let me know then, how it goes.

Comment: Glad that it helped you, happy to help. Enjoy learning and sharing knowledge here :)